# Elasticsearch: building a date_histogram with the 10 latest documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to display a histogram that, for each time point, shows the average of the 10 latest values starting from this specific time point.

Ideally, I would have a `date_histogram` aggregation that would build the buckets, and each bucket should be populated with the 10 documents which timestamp are inferior of this bucket key.

Is this even possible? Would I be better of fetching all the documents and building the histogram client side?

Let me know if I can rephrase it more clearly or if you need examples.

Edit: add an example

Here is what my current query look like:

```json
POST transactions/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    // some filters
  },
  "aggs": {
    "average_hist": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "now-24h",
          "max": "now"
        },
        "hard_bounds": {
          "min": "now-24h",
          "max": "now"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the response:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "average_hist" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1651042800",
          "key" : 1651042800000,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "average" : {
            "value" : 7.77E18
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1651046400",
          "key" : 1651046400000,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "average" : {
            "value" : 9.328E18
          }
        },
        // 23 more buckets...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To fulfil my requirements, I need to have a `doc_count` that is always equal to 10. For example the first bucket would need to be populated with the 9 previous docs starting from 1651042800. The second bucket would need to be populated with the 2 docs from the previous bucket, and the 8 previous docs starting from 1651042800 as well.

Hope this example helps.

Comment: An example always helps ;-)

Comment: @Val I added an example as requested